# ERROR: Issue with creating launcher for agent <AGENT>. The agent has not been fully initialized yet

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

We are running a Jenkins master/slave setup, where most jobs run stable.
Unfortunately there is a job that is returning an error;

> ERROR: Issue with creating launcher for agent . The agent has
>   not been fully initialized yet.

This is because the slave is not occupied and being terminates by the master (my assumption). What do we need to look into to resolve this ?

- Jenkins; jenkins-war:2.107.2
- Amazon EC2; amazon-ecs:1.14

`JNLP agent connected from ip.eu-central-1.compute.internal
Remoting version: 3.19
This is a Unix agent
Agent successfully connected and online
ERROR: Connection terminated
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:789)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
JNLP agent connected from ip.eu-central-1.compute.internal
Remoting version: 3.19
This is a Unix agent`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46067) ticket that is still open.